# Can I use Azure interactive mode for azure-cli-ml extension?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Azure CLI interactive mode `az interactive` to run below command. 
`az ml folder attach -w yhd-mlws -g yhd-mlws-rg`
It prompts me with below error message.
`az: error: unrecognized arguments: -w yhd-mlws -g yhd-mlws-rg`
BTW, both my Machine Learning workspace `yhd-mlws` and resource group `yhd-mlws-rg` had been created in my Azure subscription. Azure CLI extension for machine learning service had also been installed via `az extension add -n azure-cli-ml`.
Then I run command `az ml folder attach` without any argument. I get bellow error message.

```
Message: Error, default workspace not set and workspace name parameter not provided.
Please set a default workspace using "az ml folder attach -w myworkspace -g myresourcegroup" or provide a value for the workspace name parameter.
```

The command window exit the interactive mode after above error message. Then I try the command `az ml folder attach -w yhd-mlws -g yhd-mlws-rg` again, bingo! It works. 
Here comes my question, does azure-cli-ml extension support Azure CLI interactive mode? You know, Azure CLI interactive mode is amazing and I want to use it whenever possible. Thanks!
BTW, I'm running windows command window in Windows Server 2016 Datcenter. Azure-cli version is 2.0.79.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the interactive mode should support the `azure-cli-ml` extension, because when I run `az ml workspace list`, it works, once I pass the `-g` parameter, it gives the same error, maybe it is a bug, but I am not sure, the `interactive` is in preview currently.

[image]

If you want to run `az ml folder attach -w yhd-mlws -g yhd-mlws-rg` in the interactive mode, my workaround is to pass the `#`, i.e. `# az ml folder attach -w yhd-mlws -g yhd-mlws-rg`.

[image]

Comment: @HuodongYuan If so, could you accept it? Thank you. :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Although I'm still looking forward to seeing the real function (not workaround), it will take sometime. Thanks again.